# How to get bytes (byte[]) from an uploaded file in Grails

Tags: grails, file-upload, groovy

I have a upload form like this (`form.gsp`):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Image</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
</head>
    <body>  
        <g:uploadForm action ="upload">
            Photo: <input name="photos" type="file" />
            <g:submitButton name="upload" value="Upload" />
        </g:uploadForm>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect the user to upload any picture, and when he clicks on the `upload` button, I need some way to get the image in my controller action and passed it to the view :

```
def upload = { 
        byte[] photo = params.photos
            //other code goes here . . . .
    }
```

This throws an error :

```
Cannot cast object 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@1b40272' with class 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to class 'byte'
```

Note that I don't want these photos to be saved on my DB. Actually once the `upload` action is done, I will process with that image and show the output in `upload` view itself. So it will be good if I have a solution for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to upload the file, not store it, and display it in an `<img>` on another view in the next request, you could temporarily store it in the session:

**`grails-app/controllers/UploadController.groovy:`**

```
def upload = {
    def file = request.getFile('file')

    session.file = [
        bytes: file.inputStream.bytes,
        contentType: file.contentType
    ]

    redirect action: 'elsewhere'
}

def elsewhere = { }

def image = {
    if (!session.file) {
        response.sendError(404)
        return
    }

    def file = session.file
    session.removeAttribute 'file'

    response.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
    response.contentType = file.contentType
    response.outputStream << file.bytes
    response.outputStream.flush()

}
```

**`grails-app/views/upload/form.gsp:`**

```
<g:uploadForm action="upload">
  <input type="file" name="file"/>
  <g:submitButton name="Upload"/>
</g:uploadForm>
```

**`grails-app/views/upload/elsewhere.gsp:`**

```
<img src="${createLink(controller: 'upload', action: 'image')}"/>
```

The file will be available for a single request (since we remove it when it's displayed). You might need to implement some additional session cleanup for error cases.

You could easily adapt this to hold onto multiple files (if you're trying to stage a bunch of photo uploads), but keep in mind that each file's taking up memory.

An alternative to using the session would be to transfer the files to a temporary location on disk using [`MultipartFile#transferTo(File)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo%28java.io.File%29) and display them from there.

Comment: This looks, great but when I view the `elsewhere.gsp` I couldn't able to see any image!

Comment: Hmm, interesting. The code above worked for me, verbatim. What does the page say the source of the image is? Perhaps you can add some logging to help debug it.

Comment: Sorry it was working, I made a typo in controller name: thanks for your stuff :)

Answer (score 11):

```
def reqFile = request.getFile("photos")
InputStream file = reqFile.inputStream
byte[] bytes = file.bytes
```

**Edit**: changed the getBytes to bytes as suggested and as is a better groovy way :)

Comment: everything works fine! but if I want to display the image that user have uploaded on a view, how can I do that?

Comment: you can write your bytes to response.outputStream

Answer (score 5):

```
byte[] photo=request.getFile("photos").bytes
```

and if you want to return as an image do:

```
response.contentType="image/png" //or whatever the format is...
response.outputStream << photo
```